# Regular expression for accessing map in java script

Tags: javascript, regex

How to I fetch some rows of particular pattern ?

```
var list = {
 kk_list_name : "jack",
 kk_list_no : "123",
 kk_first_name :"Reck",
 kk_first_no : "5555"
}
```

Here I want a map with key starting with kk_list
I tried some thing like this, which obviously didnt work.

> ```
> console.log(list["kk_list_\w+"])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function filterArray( list, regex )
{
    var outputArray = {};

    for( var key in list )
    {
        if( key.match( regex ) )
        {
            outputArray[key] = list[key];
        }
    }

    return outputArray;
}

var list = {
 kk_list_name : "jack",
 kk_list_no : "123",
 kk_first_name :"Reck",
 kk_first_no : "5555"
}

console.log( filterArray( list, /kk_list_\w+/ ) );
```

It uses a function to filter the array and make a new one with the regex-selected keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the object to one with just the keys matching a specified regex using the following:

```
Object.prototype.reduce = function(regex) {
    var newObj = {}, x;
    for(x in this) if(this.hasOwnProperty(x) && (!regex || regex.test(x))) newObj[x] = this[x];
    return newObj;
};
```

And then call it as `list.reduce(/_first.*$/)` => `Object {kk_first_name: "Reck", kk_first_no: "5555"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
var list = {
 kk_list_name : "jack",
 kk_list_no : "123",
 kk_first_name :"Reck",
 kk_first_no : "5555"
}

var line=JSON.stringify(list);

var ar=line.match(/(kk_list[^" :]*)/g)

ar.forEach(function(val){
                    console.log(eval("list."+val));
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
jack  
123
```